# How to set a timeout for finding location with geo.js?

Tags: javascript, safari, timeout, geolocation

I use geo.js in my webapp to let user share their location. In most browsers it works fine, however in Safari it usually hangs up. I know there's timeout in HTML5 geolocation, is there such thing in geo.js too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try it directly when calling the getCurrentPosition method, something like:

```
geo_position_js.getCurrentPosition(show_position, error_callback, {timeout: 10000});
```